# ALIGN(n) differences in linkerscript sections, within the STM32-family

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, stm32, linker-scripts

I'm comparing linkerscripts generated by CubeMX for the STM32-microcontroller family. Let's take a look at the **STM32L476RG (NUCLEO-L476)** and the more recent **STM32F767ZI (NUCLEO-F767ZI)**.

Note: The linkerscripts are generated for the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler.

The most striking difference is in the alignment directives in the `SECTIONS` part of the linkerscript. Here is the `.isr_vector` section of the **STM32L476RG**:

```
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
```

And this is the `.isr_vector` section for the **STM32F767ZI**:

```
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
```

There are differences like this in almost all the code sections. I've made a table to compare:

```
        STM32L476RG                     STM32F767ZI
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .isr_vector    | ALIGN(8) |   | .isr_vector    | ALIGN(4) |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .text          | ALIGN(8) |   | .text          | ALIGN(4) |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .rodata        | ALIGN(8) |   | .rodata        | ALIGN(4) | 
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .ARM.extab     | ALIGN(8) |   | .ARM.extab     |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .ARM           | ALIGN(8) |   | .ARM           |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .preinit_array | ALIGN(8) |   | .preinit_array |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .init_array    | ALIGN(8) |   | .init_array    |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .fini_array    | ALIGN(8) |   | .fini_array    |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .data          | ALIGN(8) |   | .data          | ALIGN(4) |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .bss           |     /    |   | .bss           |     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| ._user_heap_st | ALIGN(8) |   | ._user_heap_st | ALIGN(8) |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
| .ARM.attributes|     /    |   | .ARM.attributes|     /    |
+----------------+----------+   +----------------+----------+
```

Given the fact that both microcontrollers have a 32-bit architecture, where do these differences come from?

---

For completeness, I've decided to add the full linkerscripts here. You can use the online diffing tool to compare them (https://www.diffchecker.com/). Below is the linkerscript for the **STM32L476RG** microcontroller:

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**
**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32L476RGTx Device with
**                1024KByte FLASH, 128KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
*****************************************************************************
** @attention
**
** <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2014 Ac6</center></h2>
**
** Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
** are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
**   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
**      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
**   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
**      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
**      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
**   3. Neither the name of Ac6 nor the names of its contributors
**      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
**      without specific prior written permission.
**
** THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
** AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
** IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
** DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
** FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
** DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
** SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
** CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
** OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
** OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20018000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 96K
RAM2 (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 32K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 1024K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : 
  { 
  . = ALIGN(8);
  *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
  . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Here is the linkerscript for the **STM32F767ZI** microcontroller:

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**
**  File        : LinkerScript.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32F767ZITx Device with
**                2048KByte FLASH, 512KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
*****************************************************************************
** @attention
**
** <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT(c) 2014 Ac6</center></h2>
**
** Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
** are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
**   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
**      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
**   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
**      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
**      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
**   3. Neither the name of Ac6 nor the names of its contributors
**      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
**      without specific prior written permission.
**
** THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
** AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
** IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
** DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
** FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
** DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
** SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
** CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
** OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
** OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20080000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 512K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 2048K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: It could be for performance as the newer chip may use a wider bus.  But it could also be a case of the M4 came out a while before the M7.  The maintainer of this code, or the new person who came along and got stuck with the job just added M7 stuff and didnt bother going back to make any consistency between the new code and prior code.  For various obvious reasons if you have had to either maintain old code or gotten stuck with someone elses.   Vendor provided libraries are pretty scary when you dig into them.  They are far from perfect, expect to find things like this without a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare badly written linker scripts.

Most of it does not make any sense:

.isr_vectors has to be 512 aligned as the SCB->VTOR requires it.
Most apps place vector table at the beginning of the FLASH/RAM - and this location is 512 aligned anyway :)

The rest  (except the stack which may be required by the interrupt entry mechanism to be 8 bytes aligned - but in this family of uCs by default (reset state of the core config registers) it is not requires) is just the imagination of the person who wrote it. They should be 4 bytes aligned to avoid performance penalties as those micros allow unaligned access.

Some people say that the buses are 64 (or 128) bits wide and such alignments may have positive effect on the performance but it is marginal if any.

If you DMA access the memory location it is good to have it aligned to avoid wait states.

Some another Cotex cores do not allow unaligned access.

PS
Remember that some memory locations (in the documentation called "Device Memory Type" must be naturally aligned - which means 4 bytes on 32bits systems)

Comment: Thank you @PeterJ_01. I've got two questions after reading your answer. **(1)** If these linkerscripts are *bad*, where can I find the *good* ones? These were given by the STMicro official CubeMX tool, to get started with their microcontrollers. **(2)** Which of the two approaches would you prefer in your microcontroller applications? The one which is inserting ALIGN(8) almost everywhere, or the one inserting ALIGN(4) here and there?

Comment: @K.Mulier As you see there important errors. The .isr.. one is only one example. In the real world you actually need to write your own ones - written for your particular needs. If you ask me about my ones - I consider the needs of my program and organize the memory accordingly.

Comment: Hi @PeterJ_01. Please tell me the *important errors* you can see in the linkerscripts from CubeMX, so I can learn from those mistakes. Writing my own linkerscripts is hopefully possible once I've seen good examples. Could you post some of your linkerscripts here, with some comments in them if you're doing special stuff? That would be awesome ^_^. I would like to make a PayPal donation to you for such efforts!

Comment: for example vector table is incorrectly aligned. There is a lot of the unneeded lines. Bad linker script oganisation which may cause problems when bin files are generated (wrong sizes) which can be important if the the image will be encrypted or/and check summed.

Comment: How should the vector table be aligned? Can you write that line as it should appear in the linkerscript?